# elastic search setup in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch

I am working on an asp.net application where I have huge database. I want to implement elastic search. Here is what I have done in code:

```
var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200/");
            var setting = new ConnectionSettings(node);
            setting.DefaultIndex("businessuser");
            client = new ElasticClient(setting);

 CanadaBusinessDBEntities db = new CanadaBusinessDBEntities();
            client.DeleteIndex("businessuser", null);
            var ListofBusiness = db.CanadaTables.ToList();
            foreach (var Business in ListofBusiness)
            {
                var resutl = client.Index(Business, null);
            }
```

This code is written in constructor which gets all records and then index them using elastic search. indexing is taking long time. I want to ask if this is correct way? I am new to elastic search. please suggest better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: One option is to use Logstash to index your data from database to elasticsearch using jdbc connection. Leave your application to do search only.

Comment: I have windows hosting. will this solution work?

Comment: Yes it will work on windows as well. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ElasticsearchContext Class of Nest.

```
private readonly ElasticsearchContext _elasticsearchContext;
private const string ConnectionString = "http://localhost:9200";
private readonly IElasticsearchMappingResolver _elasticsearchMappingResolver;


_elasticsearchMappingResolver = new ElasticsearchMappingResolver();
_elasticsearchContext = new ElasticsearchContext(ConnectionString, new ElasticsearchSerializerConfiguration(_elasticsearchMappingResolver,true,true));
```

for Delete purpose you can use like that below

```
 public void DeleteSkill(int  Id)
        {
            _elasticsearchContext.DeleteDocument<Tag>(Id);
            _elasticsearchContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```